# Add multiple checkedListbox to columns of datagrid View

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

As we can Add single checkbox to column to datagrid view column but is it possible to add checked list box to datagrid view the aim is to have a cell having multiple checkboxes.

How can we add them?

How can we access their properties,such as text and checked ?

Got some answer but i cannot understand it
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsdatacontrols/thread/6c68a44c-c4ab-4caf-94e9-249ec63a90d0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom DataGridView column. There are many articles on the web that demonstrate this; [here's one example](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0707061). Expose the checkboxes as properties to access their properties.

Comment: its bar graph not checked listbox

Comment: It's an example of creating a custom cell and column. It should be easily adaptable to your case. I doubt you're going to find an example that you can cut and paste into your code.

Comment: i found at link given and includes repaint

Answer (score 4):

*Read my comments at the bottom of this answer before using this code.*

---

As per the question **how can we access text and checkboxes from this [CheckListBox DataGridView Column](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6c68a44c-c4ab-4caf-94e9-249ec63a90d0/need-a-datagridview-custom-column-of-type-listview-or-checkedlistbox?forum=winformsdatacontrols)** :

```
public class CheckedListBoxColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public CheckedListBoxColumn()
        : base(new CheckedListBoxCell())
    {
    }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null &&
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CheckedListBoxCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CheckedListBoxCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}

public class CheckedListBoxCell : DataGridViewCell
{
    public CheckedListBoxCell()
        : base()
    {

    }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object
        initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.  
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue,
            dataGridViewCellStyle);
        CheckedListBoxEditingControl ctl =
            DataGridView.EditingControl as CheckedListBoxEditingControl;
        InitializeCheckedListBox(ctl, (ICollection)this.FormattedValue);
    }
    private void InitializeCheckedListBox(CheckedListBox ctrl, ICollection value)
    {
        ctrl.Items.Clear();
        foreach (object obj in value)
        {
            ctrl.Items.Add(obj.ToString());
        }
        ctrl.Tag = this.Value;
    }
    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(CheckedListBoxEditingControl);
        }
    }
    protected override object GetFormattedValue(object value, int rowIndex, ref DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter valueTypeConverter, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }
        return base.GetFormattedValue(value, rowIndex, ref cellStyle, valueTypeConverter, formattedValueTypeConverter, context);
    }
    public override Type FormattedValueType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(ICollection);
        }
    }
    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(ICollection);
        }
    }
    private CheckedListBox internalControl;

    protected override void Paint(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds, System.Drawing.Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
        graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor), cellBounds);

        if (internalControl == null)
        {
            internalControl = new CheckedListBox();
        }
        internalControl.Items.Clear();
        ICollection collection = value as ICollection;
        if (collection != null)
        {
            foreach (object obj in collection)
            {
                internalControl.Items.Add(obj);
            }
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(cellBounds.Width, cellBounds.Height);
            internalControl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
            graphics.DrawImage(bmp, cellBounds, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataGridView.BeginEdit(false);
        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}

class CheckedListBoxEditingControl : CheckedListBox, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
    DataGridView dataGridView;
    private bool valueChanged = false;
    int rowIndex;

    public CheckedListBoxEditingControl()
    {

    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue   
    // property.  
    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Tag;
        }
        set
        {
            //  this.Tag = value;  
        }
    }

    // Implements the   
    // IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method.  
    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(
        DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }

    // Implements the   
    // IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method.  
    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
        DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
        this.ForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
        this.BackColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex   
    // property.  
    public int EditingControlRowIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return rowIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            rowIndex = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey   
    // method.  
    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
        Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed.  
        switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
                return true;
            default:
                return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit   
    // method.  
    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
    {
        // No preparation needs to be done.  
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl  
    // .RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property.  
    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl  
    // .EditingControlDataGridView property.  
public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
{
    get
    {
        return dataGridView;
    }
    set
    {
        dataGridView = value;
    }
}

// Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl  
// .EditingControlValueChanged property.  
public bool EditingControlValueChanged
{
    get
    {
        return valueChanged;
    }
    set
    {
        valueChanged = value;
    }
}

// Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl  
// .EditingPanelCursor property.  
public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
{
    get
    {
        return base.Cursor;
    }
}
}
```

An interesting Blog post covers the problems with this class: http://dotnetgenetics.blogspot.com.au/2014/01/custom-checkedlistbox-datagridview.html

Add a property in the CheckedListBoxCell class to retrieve the checked items:

```
 public ICollection CheckedItems
 {
    get
    {
        if (internalControl == null)
            return null;
        else
        {
            if (internalControl != null)
            {
                if (internalControl.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    return internalControl.CheckedItems;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((CheckedListBox)this.DataGridView.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[ColumnIndex].DataGridView.EditingControl != null)
                    {
                        CheckedListBox checks = (CheckedListBox)this.DataGridView.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[ColumnIndex].DataGridView.EditingControl;
                        if (checks.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
                            return checks.CheckedItems;
                        else
                            return null;
                    }
                    else
                        return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method to get the checked items.

```
 private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
 {  
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();  
   foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgCheckListColumn1.Rows)  
   {  
     DataGridViewCell cell = item.Cells[1];  
     if (((cell as CheckedListBoxCell).CheckedItems != null))  
     {  
       if (((cell as CheckedListBoxCell).CheckedItems.Count > 0))  
       {  
         foreach (var checkItem in ((cell as CheckedListBoxCell).CheckedItems))  
         {  
           builder.AppendLine(String.Format("Row {0} : item: {1}", item.Index + 1, checkItem.ToString()));  
         }  
         builder.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);  
       }   
     }  
   }  
   MessageBox.Show("Checked Items: \n" + builder.ToString());  
 }
```

---

My take on all this is - **its crap** - looks crap and it behaves like crap.. even feels crap:

[image]

---

IMHO its much better tapping into a DataGridView's cell click event and popping up a CheckedListbox:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        int RowHeight1 = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Height;
        Rectangle CellRectangle1 = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false);

        CellRectangle1.X += DataGridView1.Left;
        CellRectangle1.Y += DataGridView1.Top + RowHeight1;


        checkedListBox1.Left = CellRectangle1.X;
        checkedListBox1.Top = CellRectangle1.Y;
        checkedListBox1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the method CellClick , but one thing I do not see is how you translate my checking changes into that Cell- so the CheckedListBox in the Rectangle has a check changed event, how to capture that and place the value into the datagridview cell that was clicked ? Imagine a ByteFlag where each check is a bit of the byte.

Comment: I used your code dataGridView1_CellClick above but it does not work the list box never shows up and the displaypoint is unused. Anything you might have left out ?