# CheckedListBox in DataGridview Winforms VB NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview whose data source contains a many to many relationship 
Bin {ID, Name, BinGradeID},  BinGradeID {BinID, GradeID, GradeName }, Grade {ID, Name}

I am trying to expose Grades in a CheckedListBoxColumn and right now I can not seem to get anything into the checkedlistboxcolumn

I have added the CheckedListBoxColumn to the DataGridView programatically.
I am lacking in knowing how to bind it to the data source , I have tried both the examples here [Add multiple checkedListbox to columns of datagrid View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724433/add-multiple-checkedlistbox-to-columns-of-datagrid-view)

I have tried both of the example codes posted - by Jeremy Thompson - I would like his example that looks nice but I get nothing to pop up/out like this:
[image]

I tried the other with the checkedlistboxcolumn and that does not work either.

Here is the code where I add the Column to the DataGridView

```
Dim dgvChkCol As CheckedListBoxColumn = New CheckedListBoxColumn()
dgvChkCol.DataPropertyName = "GradeID"
dgvChkCol.Name = "GradesCheckBox"
dgvChkCol.Visible = True
dgvChkCol.HeaderText = "GradesCheckBox"
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvChkCol)
```

Any code in VB or C# is fine with me - I can convert easy enough - I am just lacking in CheckedListBox and how to do it in a DataGridView

In case someone wants to see my checkedlistbox code - this is the C# converted to VBNET

```
Public Class CheckedListBoxColumn
    Inherits DataGridViewColumn
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(New CheckedListBoxCell())
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Property CellTemplate() As DataGridViewCell
        Get
            Return MyBase.CellTemplate
        End Get
        Set(value As DataGridViewCell)
            If value IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not value.[GetType]().IsAssignableFrom(GetType(CheckedListBoxCell)) Then
                Throw New InvalidCastException("Must be a CheckedListBoxCell")
            End If
            MyBase.CellTemplate = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class CheckedListBoxCell
    Inherits DataGridViewCell
    Public Sub New()

        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex As Integer, initialFormattedValue As Object, dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle)
        ' Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.  
        MyBase.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle)
        Dim ctl As CheckedListBoxEditingControl = TryCast(DataGridView.EditingControl, CheckedListBoxEditingControl)
        InitializeCheckedListBox(ctl, DirectCast(Me.FormattedValue, ICollection))
    End Sub
    Private Sub InitializeCheckedListBox(ctrl As CheckedListBox, value As ICollection)
        ctrl.Items.Clear()
        For Each obj As Object In value
            ctrl.Items.Add(obj.ToString())
        Next
        ctrl.Tag = Me.Value
    End Sub
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property EditType() As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(CheckedListBoxEditingControl)
        End Get
    End Property
    Protected Overrides Function GetFormattedValue(value As Object, rowIndex As Integer, ByRef cellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle, valueTypeConverter As System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, formattedValueTypeConverter As System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, context As DataGridViewDataErrorContexts) As Object
        If value Is Nothing Then
            Return New List(Of Object)()
        End If
        Return MyBase.GetFormattedValue(value, rowIndex, cellStyle, valueTypeConverter, formattedValueTypeConverter, context)
    End Function
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property FormattedValueType() As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(ICollection)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides Property ValueType() As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(ICollection)
        End Get
        Set(value As Type)

        End Set
    End Property
    Private internalControl As CheckedListBox

    Protected Overrides Sub Paint(graphics As System.Drawing.Graphics, clipBounds As System.Drawing.Rectangle, cellBounds As System.Drawing.Rectangle, rowIndex As Integer, cellState As DataGridViewElementStates, value As Object, _
        formattedValue As Object, errorText As String, cellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle, advancedBorderStyle As DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle, paintParts As DataGridViewPaintParts)
        MyBase.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, _
            formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts)
        graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor), cellBounds)

        If internalControl Is Nothing Then
            internalControl = New CheckedListBox()
        End If
        internalControl.Items.Clear()
        Dim collection As ICollection = TryCast(value, ICollection)
        If collection IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each obj As Object In collection
                internalControl.Items.Add(obj)
            Next
            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(cellBounds.Width, cellBounds.Height)
            internalControl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height))
            graphics.DrawImage(bmp, cellBounds, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnClick(e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
        Me.DataGridView.BeginEdit(False)
        MyBase.OnClick(e)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property CheckedItems() As ICollection 'Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.
        Get
            If internalControl Is Nothing Then
                Return Nothing
            Else
                If internalControl IsNot Nothing Then
                    If internalControl.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
                        Return internalControl.CheckedItems
                    Else
                        If DirectCast(Me.dataGridView.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(ColumnIndex).DataGridView.EditingControl, CheckedListBox) IsNot Nothing Then
                            Dim checks As CheckedListBox = DirectCast(Me.dataGridView.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(ColumnIndex).DataGridView.EditingControl, CheckedListBox)
                            If checks.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
                                Return checks.CheckedItems
                            Else
                                Return Nothing
                            End If
                        Else
                            Return Nothing
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    Return Nothing
                End If
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Class CheckedListBoxEditingControl
    Inherits CheckedListBox
    Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl
    Private dataGridView As DataGridView
    Private valueChanged As Boolean = False
    Private rowIndex As Integer


    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    ' Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue   
    ' property.  
    Public Property EditingControlFormattedValue() As Object Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue
        Get
            Return Me.Tag
        End Get
        '  this.Tag = value;  
        Set(value As Object)
        End Set
    End Property

    ' Implements the   
    ' IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method.  
    Public Function GetEditingControlFormattedValue(context As DataGridViewDataErrorContexts) As Object Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue
        Return EditingControlFormattedValue
    End Function

    ' Implements the   
    ' IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method.  
    Public Sub ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle) Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl
        Me.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font
        Me.ForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor
        Me.BackColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor
    End Sub

    ' Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex   
    ' property.  
    Public Property EditingControlRowIndex() As Integer Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex
        Get
            Return rowIndex
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            rowIndex = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey   
    ' method.  
    Public Function EditingControlWantsInputKey(key As Keys, dataGridViewWantsInputKey As Boolean) As Boolean Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey
        ' Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed.  
        Select Case key And Keys.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Left, Keys.Up, Keys.Down, Keys.Right, Keys.Home, Keys.[End], _
                Keys.PageDown, Keys.PageUp
                Return True
            Case Else
                Return Not dataGridViewWantsInputKey
        End Select
    End Function

    ' Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit   
    ' method.  
    Public Sub PrepareEditingControlForEdit(selectAll As Boolean) Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit
        ' No preparation needs to be done.  
    End Sub

    ' Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl  
    ' .RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property.  
    Public ReadOnly Property RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange() As Boolean Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

    ' Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl  
    ' .EditingControlDataGridView property.  
    Public Property EditingControlDataGridView() As DataGridView Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlDataGridView
        Get
            Return dataGridView
        End Get
        Set(value As DataGridView)
            dataGridView = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl  
    ' .EditingControlValueChanged property.  
    Public Property EditingControlValueChanged() As Boolean Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlValueChanged
        Get
            Return valueChanged
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            valueChanged = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl  
    ' .EditingPanelCursor property.  
    Public ReadOnly Property EditingPanelCursor() As Cursor Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingPanelCursor
        Get
            Return MyBase.Cursor
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: The ChecklistBox doesnt have a datasource/do databinding.  You'll have to populate and harvest selections via code. The linked post shows them being added as strings, you may need to store objects `{Id, Text}`.  As for pop up/out, look at his code - it is just a message box to debug/demo: `MessageBox.Show("Checked Items: \n" + builder.ToString());`

Comment: @Plutonix - the pop out is not the winform next to the graphic - scroll further down you will see the example that is neater and better. That is the popout I am referring to. I will try to post it to.

Comment: ...or are you asking about his second "un crap" version for the pop up?  That is just floating a CLB over the DGV so it looks like a little like a Property Editor.  Personally, I'd add a `...` button to the cell for a visual cue.

Comment: @Plutonix - yes the uncrap version - I was planning to hilite and place csv text  but the ellipse button sounds like a better idea. So I have to add the objects to the checked listbox and handle the relationship - then when the dgv is updated in any cell I need to make sure that CLB column data is updated as well. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: I am not sure that he isnt just using a standard Text column, then showing the CLB as needed (`PointToScreen` is kind of indicative).  No need for a special column if that is the case.  I'd show "Foo" if there was one item, or `3 item(s)` when there was more than one plus the ellipse/more... button.  That column would be unbound too.  The Objects for the CLB would *seem* to be needed to keep the ID and Name together.

Comment: @Plutonix as I was looking more into the CheckedListBox as I have seen examples with a Datasource being set (and my intelliesense did not show it) I looked here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx and it shows a Datasource property that is not browseable.

Comment: I was messing with the PopUp checkedlist and there are many, many issues with it - like how to know when to make it go away.  The CLB has a DataSource because it inherits from ListBox, but it is suppressed in the CLB.  The issue is that the CLB is really just a ListBox with the items drawn using the CheckBox Renderer (notice that the items themselves have no Checked Property!).  So it doesnt know how to map a Value to the CheckState

Comment: I think the *easiest* would be to have a CLB alongside the DGV and just update it when the row changes.  I think the only way to do a good job with an integral one is to combine the 2-3 approaches in the link - create a custom column which uses the dropdown CLB as the EditControl.  I *think* that is at odds with a nice ellipsis button (2 controls?) and quite possible a custom CLB with real checkboxes in it.  Maybe some events or custom formatter so something can provide the mapping.  Note how often :"custom" appears, hence the *easy* comment at the start.

Comment: @Plutonix yes you are correct it has those issues (only way I know is on focus leave - not very good) . I have been struggling with this, I have a List of Items (they never change (depending on app) and are the only allowed selections). The selected items are related to another table the DataGridView - so I have a kind of Master/Detail view where the detail is all allowed items (details being to show selected as checked) . Seeing your additional comment - at least makes me feel I am not just missing the obvious. I know others must have done this but how?

Comment: I think you already said it: a Master-Detail type thing.  The way I did this with a media cataloger was an independent control listing the Genre list.  A dedicated helper class updates the control (set the checks), then harvests the data back into a DataTable for updates.  It is a simple interface just  `Display` and `Update`  methods (of course I later complicated it to allow adds on the fly).  I have no idea what your DB layer looks like, but you'd probably have to update/insert the m:m table separately anyway, so less reason to glue it into the main DGV.